# load html head tags from one source with angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm working on an application with PHP on the server-side and Angular Js on the client side. I am relatively new to Angular Js and I'm having problems when loading the basic head tags of the html document. I would like to invoke html fragments from $scope variables defined once in a static place. For example

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope){
 $scope.stylesheets = {};
 $scope.stylesheets.style1 = '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css">';
 $scope.stylesheets.style2 = '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css">';
});
```

And the in html

```
<html>
 <head>
 {{stylesheets.style1}}
 {{stylesheets.style1}}
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>
```

I now it is not posible to bind html to the DOM through an Angular expression. But is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: i didn't tryed it yet you should use the documentation from this site http://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-bind-html.asp

Comment: You can also use html imports to get that done, you can get some more info from this site http://webcomponents.org/articles/introduction-to-html-imports/